# How to retrieve list hyperlink field values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, caml-query, hyperlink

I know how to retrieve items like Title etc. I can query the columns and fetch data. But it doesnt show the hyperlinks.

Appreciate if someone can help me out!

```
getListItem.get_item('Link').get_url();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `JavaScript Object Model`, if you need to retrieve value and link of a column of type `Hyperlink` then following methods are used.

1. `get_description()`: It will fetch the description of the link you have given
2. `get_url()`: It will fetch the URL.

> **Note**: The method which you have used is correct, in case you do not get values in it, then you must check the list items.

**Refer below example**:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var myListItem = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName").getItemById(1);
context.load(myListItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    alert(myListItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_description());
    alert(myListItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_url());

},function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());});
```

Comment: Why did you add .getItemById(1);? and why is it needed?

Comment: @Sunreuz : Its not needed. Its just an example, which directly gets a list item whose ID is 1. You can also get all items loop them and get URL. See this another example https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce625f29-c37e-4ed8-a4fe-f9aed18dec63/retrieve-url-value-from-column-in-csom-javascript which is slightly different. Here he first gets Item in variable, then on that calls `get_url()` function.

Comment: It works now. But the problem is its not clickable link. Displaying only the URL. So how can I get as a clickable link for every item that are fetched from the list?

Comment: Are you generating any type of html out of the result you get? If so then you can place this link in href attribute of anchor tag.

Comment: The column (hyperlink) has some items example www.google.com or www.youtube.com. When I retreive the items and present on my site it should be clickable. I put this code but then it made all the items to 1 single link. `listItemInfo += "<li style='height: 20px;'>" + oListItem.get_item('Title') + " " + oListItem.get_item('Link').get_url() + "</li>";
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<a href=" + listItemInfo + "</a>";`

Comment: I want every item to be clickable link. Would be much appreicated if you could show me :

Answer (score 2):

```
string strurl = ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue)(item["destinationURL"])).Url;
```

Using CSOM, Convert the item to a FieldURLValue and then get the URL from that object

Comment: Would you please explain your code. Please provide brief explanations on what was the problem and how your code will solve it. This will be very helpful for other visitors

Comment: @Asad Refai,  I just gave him the answer using CSOM. Convert the item to a FieldURLValue and then get the URL from that object.

Comment: Can you please update your answer, with this explanation please

Comment: @AsadRefai, Thanks buddy! I am newbie. Will update the answer.

Comment: Everyone at some point are newbies, you can read this help at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/answering and get idea about working of SP.SE. Continue your good contribution to the site. :)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint List's `Hyperlink` Column have two values

1. **Url**: To get value of this url use - `ListItem.get_item('HyperlinkColumnName').get_url()`
2. **Description**: To get value of this use -  `ListItem.get_item('HyperlinkColumnName').get_description()`

Comment: It doesnt work I have tested it. I get this error "it is not possible to retrieve the property get_url for a reference that is undefined or null". In sharepoint list I have a column name "Link". I added two different URL:s.

Comment: Never mind now I can fetch the hyperlinks from my column. But the thing is its not clickable. You know how to make it clickable?

Comment: @Sunreuz: To make link clickable you need to make description as hyperlink using JavaScript and add this element into section. Example - <a href='+ListItem.get_item('HyperlinkColumnName').get_url()+'> ListItem.get_item('HyperlinkColumnName').get_description() </a>

Comment: I get some error message but is it like this?  `while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var listItem = enumerator.get_current();

                itemString += listItem.get_item('Title') + "<br/>" + "<a href=" + ListItem.get_item('Link').get_url() +'> ListItem.get_item('Link').get_description() + "</a>";
                $('#divAllaListItems').html(itemString);
            }`

Comment: Thank you I figured it out with some help. Now it works.